# Visual Studio perpetually runs TWO indexing tasks simultaneously

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm running Visual Studio 2022 version 17.9.2  I've seen many threads about it perpetually indexing a solution.  I'm not too concerned about that.  What confuses me is that when I look at the list of running tasks, there are always TWO indexing tasks listed, going at the same time I must assume

Any idea why this might be and how I might address it?  I can live with one perpetually indexing tasks but two seems a bit excessive.

[image]